# How can I do connection connection pooling in Nodejs MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using using NodeJS and MongoDb as a backend service in my android application.I want to know how can I pool connections so that it minimize the load on server and make fast operations and how to close the connection
to database after performing operation.

This is what I have been done so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const env = require('dotenv').config();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.post('/add', (req,res) => {


  var data = {

    User_id: req.body.userId,
    Email:req.body.email,
    Name: req.body.name,
    Book_name: req.body.bookName,
  };

  MongoClient.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser:true} ,(err,client) => {

          if(err){

            console.log("Error".red, +err);
          }
          else{

            var collect = client.db('Mydb').collection('Books');

            collect.insertOne(data, (err,resp) =>{

                  if(err){

                    console.log("Error", +err);
                  }
                  else{

                    console.log("Successfully inserted");
                  }

                  client.close();
            });

        }

     });

 });

  app.listen(port,() => {

       console.log("App is running on:" +port);
  });
```

Someone please let me know what else need to be added in above code to achieve desired results.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MongoClient` by default sets up a connection pool of size 5. You can initiliaze the connection and reuse it.

```
let connection;
MongoClient.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser:true} ,(err,client) => {
  if(err){
    console.log("Error".red, +err);
  }
  connection = client;
  // maybe move your app.listen here to make sure server is started after connection is acquired or something equivalent
})

// elsewhere after connection is established:
connection.db('Mydb').collection('Books');
```

To increase/decrease the pool size you can pass the `poolSize` option with the required number.

Comment: where should I use poolSize and what maximum number can we give it to.

Comment: `where should I use poolSize` in your options ex: `{useNewUrlParser:true, poolSize: 6}`  as for maximum number, it's advisable not to allocate beyond your cpus total available thread